# Why does the tqwt function in matlab give error?

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

```
load wavsheep
plot(tsh,sheep)
axis tight
title('"I saw the sheep."')
xlabel("Time (sec)")
ylabel("Amplitude")
wt = tqwt(sheep);
```

I was trying to run this sample code from matlab but I kept getting this error: Unrecognized function or variable 'tqwt'. Can someone help me find out the mistake?

Comment: With the information you provide, it looks like you simply don't have that function. Do you have the Wavelet Toolbox? What does `which tqwt` output?

Comment: Yes i have the wavelet toolbox. I say this because I checked with wavedec and it is working. tqwt gives the Tunable Q wavelet transform.

Answer (score 2):

[`tqwt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/tqwt.html) is part of the Wavelet Toolbox and was introduced in R2021b. It will not exist if your version of MATLAB is older, or if you don’t have the Wavelet Toolbox installed.